# Perform cloud formation only if any changes in lambda using AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am uisng AWS Code pipeline to perform cloud formation. My source code is committed in GitHub repository. When ever a commit is happening in my github repository, AWS Code Pipeline will starts its execution and perform the cloud formation. These functionalities are working fine.

In my project I have multiple modules. So if a user is modified only in one module, the entire module's lambda's are updated. Is there any way to restrict this using AWS Code Pipeline.

My Code Pipeline has 3 stages.

1. Source
2. Build
3. Deploy

The following is the snapshot of my code pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Can you push your each module on different branch?

Comment: That is not possible. Earlier we are using cloud 9 for cloud formation. Currently trying to automate that process using code pipeline. All modules will be committed to 'develop' branch.

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact issue we faced recently and while I see comments mentioning that it isn't possible to achieve with a single repository, I have found a workaround!

Generally, the code pipeline is triggered by a CloudWatch event listening to the GitHub/Code Commit repository. Rather than triggering the pipeline, I made the CloudWatch event trigger a lambda function. In the lambda, we can write the logic to execute the pipeline(s) only for module which has changes. This works really nicely and provides a lot of control over the pipeline execution. This way multiple pipeline can be created from  a single repository, solving the problem mention in the question.

[image: Multiple pipeline from a repository structure]

Lambda logic can be something like:

```
import boto3

# Map config files to pipelines
project_pipeline_mapping = {
        "CodeQuality_ScoreCard" : "test-pipeline-code-quality",
        "ProductQuality_ScoreCard" : "test-product-quality-pipeline"
        }

files_to_ignore = [ "readme.md" ]

codecommit_client = boto3.client('codecommit')
codepipeline_client = boto3.client('codepipeline')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    projects_changed = []
    # Extract commits
    print("\n EVENT::: " , event)
    old_commit_id = event["detail"]["oldCommitId"]
    new_commit_id = event["detail"]["commitId"]
    # Get commit differences
    codecommit_response = codecommit_client.get_differences(
        repositoryName="ScorecardAPI",
        beforeCommitSpecifier=str(old_commit_id),
        afterCommitSpecifier=str(new_commit_id)
    )
    print ("\n Code commit response: ",  codecommit_response)
    
    # Search commit differences for files that trigger executions
    for difference in codecommit_response["differences"]:
        file_name = difference["afterBlob"]["path"]
        
        project_name = file_name.split('/')[0]
        
        print("\nChanged project: ", project_name)
        
        # If project corresponds to pipeline, add it to the pipeline array
        if project_name in project_pipeline_mapping:
            projects_changed.insert(len(projects_changed),project_name)
            
    
    projects_changed = list(dict.fromkeys(projects_changed))
    print("pipeline(s) to be executed: ", projects_changed)
    
    for project in projects_changed:
        codepipeline_response = codepipeline_client.start_pipeline_execution(
                name=project_pipeline_mapping[project]
                )
```

Check AWS blog on this topic: [Customizing triggers for AWS CodePipeline with AWS Lambda and Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/)

Comment: what will be your source stage while creating pipeline , since there are no option for lambda while creating source stage for pipeline

Comment: Source would be the code commit repository. Lambda would be registered as the target of the cloudwatch rule which is monitoring the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and eventually we came to conclusion that this is not exactly possible. So unless you separate your modules into different repos and make separate pipelines for each of them  it is always going to execute everything. 
The good thing is that with each execution of the pipeline it is not entirely redeploying everything when the cloud formation is executed. In the deploy stage you can add Create Changeset part which is basically going to detect what is changed from the previous CloudFormation deployment and it is going to redeploy only those parts and will not touch anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not model this as a pipeline per module?

Comment: That will be the last option if can not find any other workaround